# How to set up permissions to OneNote pages?

Tags: 2010, permissions, office-web-apps

I have a OneNote notebook in my SharePoint 2010. I also have the Office Web Apps turned on. I am wondering if there is a way to grant permissions to a particular page / section in that OneNote file.

How can you grant permission to a page?

The reason I'ma asking is that I have a private OneNote but I want to expose one page for "Domain Users". Is it possible?

EDIT: I want to expose the OneNote pages (or sections) via Office Web Apps to "Domain Users" when it is under SharePoint permissions system. So for example: Read for "Domain Users" to a page / section and ReadWrite to some other Active Directory group.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot password protect at the page level in OneNote. You can only password protect a section or notebook.  Also remember that audio recordings cannot be password protected, and protected sections will not appear in search results.

OneNote can also be secured at the Notebook level using regular SharePoint permissions.

[image: Password protect a OneNote Section]

[image: Password protect a OneNote Notebook in SharePoint]

Comment: This is the oposite of what I want. I want to expose the OneNote pages (or sections) via Office Web Apps to "Domain Users" when it is under SharePoint permissions system. So for example: Read for "Domain Users" to a page / section and ReadWrite to some other Active Directory group.

Comment: Sorry but that's what OneNote provides. Password protect the parts you don't want others to see. Use SharePoint permissions to control who can write to the unprotected sections.

Comment: You will only be able to use the SharePoint permission system at the Notebook level, not at the page or section level.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a password for a section by right clicking the section title and select 'Password proctect this section...' this will prevent people from seeing the pages in the section in OWA and you can only see it in the client if you enter the password.

Comment: This is the oposite of what I want. I want to expose the OneNote pages (or sections) via Office Web Apps to "Domain Users" when it is under SharePoint permissions system. So for example: Read for "Domain Users" to a page / section and ReadWrite to some other Active Directory group.